# C++ function template argument with templated type struct woes

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, arguments

This code unexplicably doesn't compile:

```
struct sometype
{
    template <typename T>
    T* get() { return nullptr; }
};

template <typename T>
struct anothertype
{
#if 1
    template <typename T2> struct some_wrapper { typedef T2 type; };
    typedef typename some_wrapper<sometype>::type thetype;
#else
    typedef sometype thetype;
#endif
    typedef thetype* Ptr;

    Ptr m_ptr;
    T* get() { return m_ptr->get<T>(); }
};
```

If I change the `#if` argument to 0, it is somehow fixed. Can somebody shed some light in this? Please note that the apparently pointless `some_wrapper` thing actually does something useful in my real code.

I'm using g++ 4.7.1 with `-fstd=gnu++11`, the error is as follows (pointing to the line where I declare `anothertype<T>::get`:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

Comment: If you run exactly the code that you posted through your compiler, do you get that error?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas http://ideone.com/N8dQoj (exactly the code from the question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should fix your function call as follows, adding the `template` keyword:

```
T* get() { return m_ptr->template get<T>(); }
```

You can check [this link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fkeyword_template_qualifier.htm) for an explanation of the syntax.

Answer (score 8):

It's tough to tell with all your typedefs, but I'd wager you need:

```
m_ptr->template get<T>();
```

Comment: But ... why? `m_ptr` is *always* `sometype*`.

Comment: @ipc he has `#if 1` which will be true, so `m_ptr` is a `typename some_wrapper<sometype>::type*`, a dependent type

Comment: Dependent on what? "Expressions may be type-dependent (on the type of a template parameter)". There is no template parameter involved in `some_wrapper<sometype>::type*`.

Comment: @ipc: What is not immediately obvious is why that makes a difference... The reason why it matters is that `some_wrapper` is really `anothertype<T>::some_wrapper`, and thus any name dependent on `some_wrapper` becomes a dependent name, and to resolve dependent names you need the additional `typename` and `template` keywords. [In exactly the same way that typename is needed in `typedef typename some_wrapper<sometype>::type thetype;`]

Comment: @ipc: A corollary of my last comment which again, might not be apparent is that you can *change* what a nested type/template is after the definition: `template <typename T> struct A { struct B {int x;}; static int size() { return sizeof(B); } }; template <> struct A<int>::B { int y[2]; }; int main() { std::cout << A<int>::size(); };` An specialization of `A<int>::B` after the class template is defined can change the meaning of member functions already defined.

Comment: @ipc: Not *always*.  It would be legal to explicitly specialize `anothertype<int>::some_wrapper<sometype>` (as long as it hasn't yet been instantiated).